# Combining "text" and the number of plotted points on a graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to show as a subtitle, for example, "N=24" but 24 is the count of the plotted points in ggplot. I cannot seem to find a way to combine the text and calculation without manually changing the count number every time. Is there a way to combine "text" and a calculation in a subtitle in ggplot2?

I have tried to use paste() and sprintf(), but they do not seem to work as intended and are only displaying the text part.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `glue` package for this:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "This is the title",
       subtitle = glue::glue("There are N = {nrow(mtcars)} dots"))
```

[image]

Comment: Is `nrow` not a bit risky when there are NAs in your dataset?

Comment: Good point. One can use `na.omit`. I'm no expert in the `ggplot2` machinery but maybe there is an internal function/parameter that tells how many points there are in the plot? e.g. even accounting for restrictions of the axes...

Comment: Thanks, glue seems to make it work. But as Quinten said, there are some values which are missing and thus not included in the graph. I managed to exclude them using is.na labs(y="", x="", title ="2016",
       subtitle = glue::glue("N = {nrow(df16[!is.na(df16$Conc_CHL_arithMean),])}"))